# SSO for Dynamics NAV and AZURE Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

I have some problem. When i trying configure SSO (Dynamics NAV and Azure AD) using powershell i saw this error:

> The prerequisites for validating the Office 365 tenant configuration
>   are not installed on this computer.
>
> ```
>     Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals can be downloaded and installed from
>
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=330113
>     Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell can be downloaded and installed from
>
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=330114
> ```
>
> At I:\New
>   folder\WindowsPowerShellScripts\NAVOffice365Administration\Set-NavSingleSignOnWithOffice365.ps1:327
>   char:9
>
> - throw New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.ItemN ...
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SessionStateException
>   ```

I installed these extensions but the error remained. Please, help me.

Comment: Hi all, I found the answer to my question))
Install-Module MSOnline - run this command in powershell and ready)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that finds this, you need to run these two commands:

```
Install-Module -Name MSOnline
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
```

If you receive an error trying to install, you need to download and install the latest Windows Management Framework, which at the time of this comment is 5.1: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616